# Как я могу использовать массив из файлов ресурсов java

Tags: java, массивы

У меня есть большой массив, больше 64кб, я хочу закинуть его в ресурсы и юзать оттуда, как мне это сделать?
Спасибо!

Comment: БД пробовали ??

Comment: Нет, нужно именно из ресурсов

Comment: нужно определить как их записать в файл, написать функцию записи. после написать функцию, которая из файла вернет нужную структуру

Comment: Массив можно разбить по 16к и так испрльзовать